# How to emulate a File field in Salesforce?

Tags: files

I have a requirement to implement several file fields for a Custom Object, however as far as I know you cannot create 'file fields' and detect if they are null/not null and use them in business logic. What I would like to express is that certain attributes cannot obtain a certain value unless two files have been uploaded by them

Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would create two fields on the UI, both checkbox. (File 1 Uploaded and File 2 Uploaded)

Then a **custom interface** where user uploads those files using the standard file upload component.

When the user uploads the files, I would mark corresponding checkbox a true.

Also, I would write a validation that if those two fields are not true, do not let a user update some specific attributes.

**Other things to take care of**

- Do not let people upload files from standard UI.

Comment: How do you disable it? Thanks

Comment: If you are talking about files upload from standard UI, I would remove the files related list from the UI